# Google CSE: File uploading is not successful

Tags: google-custom-search

I'm getting the above error when I try uploading an auto-suggest xml file to Google's custom site search. I tried trimming the file down to the bear minimum to see if I could isolate the problem but even the following won't upload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Autocompletions>
    <Autocompletion term="My term" type="1" />
</Autocompletions>
```

Am I missing something blindingly obvious?

Kind regards,
Karl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, despite the Google information to the contrary, that the 'language' attribute is required even if it's value is blank. I added that and the file was successfully imported.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Autocompletions>
    <Autocompletion term="My term" type="1" language="" />
</Autocompletions>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your encoding is UTF-8. Also, `term=""` i.e. an empty term should not be there in the XML file.